# Didnt realize "aspx?URL=http://cuz.pw/" added to url. Am i scammed?

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, phishing

I just googled a website and sent my login&password. But just after i realized that at the end of url of website there was an extra "aspx?URL=http://cuz.pw/"

So what does it stand for? Is my login information was sent to somewhere else and stolen?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about logging in to a website.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any information on http://cuz.pw/, but considering it throws a 404 error when I try to access the site and it is in all Chinese, it would probably be for the best that you reset your passwords.